# Ionic Datetime picker timezone issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, datetimepicker

I have this date getting from an API Call in a JSON Format: `CreatedOn : 2018-08-27T05:11:29.000Z`

When I open the form, I am setting the datetime picker to that field.

```
 <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY h:mm A" pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY h:mm A"
                 [(ngModel)]="Task.CreatedOn"></ion-datetime>
```

**Getting here `Aug 27 2018 5:11 AM` which is wrong**

I am also showing the same date with angular.

```
<h6>{{Task.CreatedOn | date : 'MMMM d,yyyy At hh:mma' }}</h6>
```

**Getting here `August 27,2018 At 08:11AM` Which is right.**

I think there is a timezone issue with the datetime picker when I am setting it.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular formatToLocal pipe which will internally convert using moment.

```
<ion-datetime 
  displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY h:mm A" 
  pickerFormat="MMM DD YYYY h:mm A" 
  [ngModel]="Task.CreatedOn | formatToLocal" 
  (ngModelChange)="Task.CreatedOn=$event">
</ion-datetime>
```

**PIPE:**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core'
import moment from 'moment';
@Pipe({ name: 'formatToLocal'})
export class FormatToLocal implements PipeTransform{
  transform(val) {
    if(val){
    return moment(val).format();  
    }
  } 
}
```